# Filter function on a table with specific format contents google-sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have this sheet with a list of matches that i want to filter on another page (by name, win/lost, date etc.) but they have multiple rows on each of them, how can i specify the format of each selection? thanks!
[image]

Edit:
this should be the desired outcome example: a list of the multiple rows that match the filter options (I tryed with filter() but only takes me individual rows, ex: if i filter by patch it gives me only one name on the blue/red draft instead of all 5 rows) Here is a sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NlAG6kt6RsqzOJ3HgYwmyaKqF01gM364cv8AcjDtt9o/edit?usp=sharing

What im looking for (non related filters):[image]

What im getting:[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a sample sheet *without any sensitive data* along with an expected vs actual output so that we can understand what your purpose and problem is? Thanks ! :D

Comment: Done! Let me know if you need more information ^^

Comment: Would you be opened to an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) solution or do you exclusively want to use Google Sheet functions?

Comment: whatever its the best option, no pref. I said query cz its what im used to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution is a simple example on [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) on how you can achieve this with the [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) and [getting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) values. I just implemented this on the `Patch` dropdown but this illustrates how it would be for the rest of items too.

The following piece of code has self-explanatory comments:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get both sheets
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Stats');
  var matchSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Match History');


  // check if the cell modified is the right cell on the right sheet
  if(e.range.getColumn()==3 && e.range.getRow()==6 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()==='Stats'){

    // Get all the values available for patch
    var patches = matchSheet.getRange(3,2,matchSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();

    // iterate over all the patches values
    for(i=0;i<patches.length;i++){

      // if there is a match with the selected value from the dropdown
      if(patches[i]===e.range.getValue()){
        // get the range of the next 5 rows and the next 10 columns from the original sheet
        // each patch is a merge of 5 rows, thus taking the next 5 rows as the range
        var pasteValues = matchSheet.getRange(i+ 3,2,5,10).getValues();
        // append these values in the row after the last written cell in the right place of stats
        sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,2,5,10).setValues(pasteValues)
      }
    }

  }
  
}
```